# Grouping elements into a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-itertools

I want to group elements into a list of list based on the indexing
Starting with the first position in data, go until the next False. That's a grouping. Continue until the last element.

```
data = ['a','b','c','d','e','f'] 
indexer = [True, True, False, False, True, True]
```

Outcome would be:

```
[['a','b','c'], ['d'], ['e','f'] ]
```

Is itertools groupby the right solution? I'm a little confused about how to implement it.

Comment: not sure it's even grouping, it's more like, iterate over and when you reach `False` create a new list and even that wouldn't work, maybe it's create a new list after a `False`

Comment: I don't understand the description of the problem. I think the outcome should instead be `[['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd'], ['e', 'f']]`. What have I misunderstood?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply append values to a temporary list and when you reach a `False`, create a new temporary list, first appending the last one to the resulting list, so basically, create a list after each `False`, lastly if necessary append the last temporary list to the result:

```py
data = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
indexer = [True, True, False, False, True, True]

result, temp = [], []
for value, index in zip(data, indexer):
    temp.append(value)
    if not index:
        result.append(temp)
        temp = []
if temp:
    result.append(temp)

print(result)
# [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d'], ['e', 'f']]
```

Answer (score 5):

Use [`accumulate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate) then [`groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate)

```
from itertools import groupby, accumulate
from operator import itemgetter

data = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
indexer = [True, True, False, False, True, True]


groups = accumulate((not b for b in indexer), initial=0)
res = [[v for _, v in vs] for k, vs in groupby(zip(groups, data), key=itemgetter(0))]
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
[['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d'], ['e', 'f']]
```

In your particular example the variable groups is equivalent to:

```
[0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2]  # print(list(groups))
```

the idea is change the *group id* every time you encounter a `False` value, hence the need to negate it.

As an alternative you could use a variation on @Matiiss idea (all credit to him):

```
res, end = [], True
for d, i in zip(data, indexer):
    if end:
        res.append([])
    res[-1].append(d)
    end = not i

print(res)
```

**Note:** In Python you can directly sum booleans because [they are integers](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#bool).

Comment: Wow this is so clever!

Comment: clever again XD

Answer (score 1):

Variation of Dani's without itemgetter, instead grouping the pure group numbers and zipping with the data (iterator) later ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY/NDoMgEITvPMXehIRDk1566bVP0JsxDQq2JApkWU3ty1vW/nj5WJhhBtJCjxiOp4Tr2mMcwZNDinHI4McUkeCOcUrtosF03TROgyEnhDVk4Ax1ZSoNVcvoGJbhGH3VCB@sezpk4xUnp@HDixnyvuxK88/lR0ieldjqcznb66UMkaCFPmKhD/DtUbpMnrwZzgcl0PGturab76bBsvXlk5xz2XB485PmzNr3p/JTqRqR0AeSJUit6xs)):

```
from itertools import groupby, accumulate

data = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
indexer = [True, True, False, False, True, True]

data = iter(data)
groups = accumulate((not b for b in indexer), initial=0)
res = [[d for _, d in zip(vs, data)] for _, vs in groupby(groups)]
print(res)
```

Two more ways using that shift-the-indexer-so-we-split-***before***-False idea ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jU47DsIwDN1zirelERELC6rEygnYqgyBpCISSiO3SMDlQ5wChQ0Pz7L9Pk736TzEzTZRzs5OFjt00koNeWQ4MTgGz9BLI0J0/uaJiQe6eo0Z9/YyLm25GCHIj8w2oh8ITiMgRDxCajhQo6sagxVe1qoVKBV6xGFCmCeuYrS2KfnoGkLLlqre6L11SohEIU5NoapP8kyqCmfq8O8nP4@giL6jzHdYzk8)):

```
res = []
for d, i in zip(data, [False] + indexer):
    if not i:
        res.append(r := [])
    r.append(d)
```

```
res = [
    r := [d]
    for d, i in zip(data, [False] + indexer)
    if not i or r.append(d)
]
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple approach is to iterate over `indexer` using `enumerate()`:

```py
groups, start = [], 0
for end, boolVal in enumerate(indexer):
    if not boolVal:
        groups.append(data[start:end + 1])
        start = end + 1
if start < len(data):
    groups.append(data[start:])
```

Output:

```
[['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d'], ['e', 'f']]
```